# Dieffenbachia plant

Tags: houseplants

I have a very big and beautiful Dieffenbachia. How do I get these plants to regrow? Do I take a piece from the roots or can roots be grown from leaves? My plant is over 6 feet and growing. I feed it with all my veggies: I make a brew and it loves it. It has some sick leaves lately: what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Please add a photograph of your plant because that will help us to diagnose any problems it may have. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Hi and welcome from me too! It looks like you might have two questions here. Do you want to learn how to grow a second plant from this one, and also find out why the leaves are sick? Could you clarify that please, so we can get a better idea of how to help you. Thanks!